# What are the words that are missing after the 的 so that the sentences make sense？

Tags: grammar

The following is a picture of part of a notice about housing project in China, in which there are some sentences ending with the marker of adjective 的 that make the sentences incomplete.

Perhaps it is due to the special usage of legal Chinese, but what are the parts or words that are missing?

[image]

Comment: maybe 的 corresponds to "in case of"  placed at the beginning of corresponding phrase, (user could not find online sources documenting such use in legal documents，although suspects having read this once), it can of course be thought of as abbreviation of 的话。

Comment: search for more examples of indicated meaning of 的 in 合同（contracts）has led to following examples at http://www.liuxue86.com/a/2541184.html
第六条 乙方逾期付款的处理 如超过上述约定期限  **的**  ，甲方有权按照下述约定，追究乙方违约 责任，约定为。。。
。。。未达到国家规定标准和承诺  **的**  ，甲方应承担责任。

。。。五、 此合同双方签字时生效，任何一方不得违反，如违反，应当向另一方承担违约金5万元，违约金不足以弥补损失  **的**  ，守约方还有权继续主张损失。

Comment: possible reason for dictionaries or grammars not providing information about "special" use of 的 in e.g. contract language: subordinate complex sentences 偏正复句
can be of the contracted type 紧缩句 （e.g. w/o conjunctions 连词) and the subordinate (conditional) clause may be a 是--的 sentence with 是  missing.

Comment: note answer to question submitted to bkrs/forum, https://bkrs.info/taolun/thread-135682.html   的 at the end of a sentence signifies situation, therefore translation "in case that, if"  is possible, bkrs:的 2)в) "indicates a certain situation" 
大星期天的，你怎么不去玩儿玩儿？  
无缘无故的你着什么急

Comment: @user6065 There are two phrases ending with 的 in your sample above, I am confused， please translate the sentence into English?Especially大星期天的, what does it mean?

Comment: 大星期天的, 你怎麽不去玩儿玩儿? It's Sunday, isn't it, why don't you take it easy and relax ? According to bkrs 的 points to the situation of it being Sunday. 无缘无故的你着什么急. Why worry for no reason at all. According to bkrs 的 points to the situation of there being no reason at all.

Comment: Don't understand why 今天是星期天 became 大星期天的, where are the 大 and 的?

Comment: what ..., who ..., in which ...

Answer (score 1):

The omitted word in all three cases is 人。

In Chinese it is common practice in written and in speech to omit **generic nouns** after a 的，i.e. when the generic noun is modified by a noun phrase, like a relative clause or an adjective. 
In case of a relative clause, as your examples are, you could translate the ~ 的（人） into something like "those who [...]"

As an example, other generic nouns that admit this behavior are 事 (thing, matter) and 东西 (physical thing, stuff).

> 我很饿的，我想吃好吃的  
>   I'm hungry, I want to eat tasty *stuff*.

Comment: That's basically it. With that being said, in the example you gave: 我很饿的is OK, but sounds exotic. It sounds more natural if you drop that 的. In other words: 我很饿，我想吃好吃的。

Comment: The 的 there would be an emphasis particle, not a modifier. It is a colloquial way of conveying a playful tone.

Answer (score 0):

The omitted word is the subject.

"主動放棄購買的" can mean 主動放棄購買的(人), 主動放棄購買的(買家) or "主動放棄購買的(申請者)

If the subject is not omitted, for example,  in "主動放棄購買的買家":

- "買家" is the subject noun
- "主動放棄購買的" is the adjectival clause,
- [**主動放棄購買的**][買家] = [the buyer][**who gave up the purchase on his or her own**]

You can translate "主動放棄購買**的**" as "**the one who** gave up the purchase on his or her own"

Answer (score 0):

In 主动放弃购买的， 反悔的 and 最终未能通过自治区房改部门资格审核的， 的 is used, at the end, to set a condition or a scope. That scope could be any single person, family, company or any other groups/organizations.

The reason why they don't mention the target for those attributive phrases is that the target could involve all kinds of peoples/groups. In this way, the certain criteria, condition or scope would be set.